# Numerical integration of a 2-dim complex function in C++?

Tags: c++, math, numerical-integration, numerical-analysis

I am trying to integrate this integral numerically (so without evaluating the primitive) in C++:

[image]

It is simpler than what it seems, in fact I know which algorithm I can implement to solve it (I consider f*Y*sin as func(th,phi) and integrate it with trapezoidal rule in 2-D). The only problem is that Y is complex and in particular is proportional to e^ikx. How should I proceed with this problem? Should I modify my integral in a way or should I apply numerical integration to real and imaginary part separately?

**EDIT**

I found this formula:

[image]

maybe it can be used to integrade real and complex part separated and numerically?

Comment: Maybe this gets you started : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146612/algorithm-for-contour-integration-c. At least have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

Comment: @PepijnKramer I added an Edit to my question, do you think the algorithm I put is good?

Comment: What is your general intention with this? Do you just need the integration for a bigger project or is the journey the award and you want to explicitly implement this integration?

Comment: @mpeschke I am implementin this because I like learning new programming features when developing new stuff. So I just want to know ho to do it in an optimal way

Comment: Gianluca, since theta and phi are real variables, you can just write the integrand as (real part + imaginary unit times imaginary part) and integrate them separately, then your final result is (real integral + imaginary unit times imaginary integral). When the variable of integration is complex, then you need to deal with contour integrals, but not here, it's simpler. The formula you showed for the trapezoidal rule in two dimensions is good; there are many other rules for numerical integration, but that's good enough to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by simply integrating real and imaginary part separately. The complete code can be found in [this](https://github.com/JustWhit3/SAFD-algorithm/blob/main/src/functions.cpp) repository, within the complete algorithm definition to integrate the function of the first image I posted.